# Find all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of T

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose n is a positive integer and $T\in \mathcal L \left({F^n}\right)$ is difined by 
$$T(x_1,...x_n)=(x_1+...+x_n,x_1+...+x_n)$$

In other words, T is the operator whose matrix (with respect to the standard basis) consists of all 1’s. Find all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $T.$ Find all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $T$.

I have a solution but I am trying to understand all the steps:

My attempt:

My first question is, how would we know that the matrix contains all 1's if it didn't tell us?

My proof: Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $T$. Then for $T\in \mathcal L \left({F^n}\right)$, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of T such that there exists a $v \in V$ for $v \neq 0$ such that $Tv= \lambda v$. Now from the equation in the question, $Tx=\lambda x$ we get

(1) $\lambda x_1=\lambda x_2=...\lambda x_n$ [my second question, how do we get this?]

I will write the rest of the proof after my questions are answered.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix has only $1$s because of the formula(e) for $T(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$.

If $v\neq 0$ is an eigenvector, there exists $\lambda$ such that $T(v)=\lambda v$, which means explicitly, coordinate by coordinate, that
\begin{cases}
x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n=\lambda x_1\\
x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n=\lambda x_2 \\
\vdots\\
x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n=\lambda x_n
\end{cases}
Thus $\;\lambda x_1=\lambda x_2=\dots=\lambda x_n$.

Now, either $\lambda =0$, and the corresponding eigenspace is the kernel of $T$, defined by the single equation $\;x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n=0$. It has dimension $n-1$.

Or $\lambda\ne 0$, and the above equation implies $\;x_1=x_2=\dots=x_n$. As one $x_i$ has to be non-zero, by definition of an eigenvector, they're all non-zero, and equal. We may suppose $x_i=1$ for all $i$,and the first series of equations simply reduces to
$$1+1+\dots+1=\lambda\quad(n \text{ terms}).$$

Comment: Thank you @Bernard. I continue on my next post

Comment: How do you know that for $\lambda = 0$ the dimension is n-1 ?

Comment: The kernel is defined by a single equation. The number of independent linear equations which define a subspace is equal to the *codimension*  of the subspace.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Bernard, now to continue and edit the proof:

Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of T. Then if $x \neq 0$, there exists a $Tx=\lambda x$. So,

\begin{cases}
x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n=\lambda x_1\\
x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n=\lambda x_2 \\
\vdots\\
x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n=\lambda x_n
\end{cases}

Thus, $\lambda x_1 = \lambda x_2 = ... =\lambda x_n$

If $\lambda = 0$ then $Tx=\lambda x= 0$ so $x_1+x_2+...+x_n=0$ or $x_1 =  x_2 = ... =x_n$. This is the eigenspace of $\lambda = 0$ since by definition, eigeinspace is defined by $Tx = \lambda x =0$ (because $null(T-\lambda I)=Tx= \lambda x =0)$

The next step is... This imples that $$nx_1=\lambda x_1$$
Why is this the case? I am trying to understand this problem step by step. Thank you!

Comment: I've completed my answer. Is it clear now?